# Python keyboard enter isnt working on a website while every other key is

Tags: python, pynput

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import json

keyboard = Controller()
#json part

with open('daten.json') as file:
        data = json.load(file)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://srsbstudy.typeform.com/to/ZNqPzv')

Name = driver.find_element_by_id('email-7c971ed6b4be6cc6') 
Name.send_keys(data["Mail"])

keyboard.press("enter")
```

*If i now let ir run I keep getting a error:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://srsbstudy.typeform.com/to/ZNqPzv')

Name = driver.find_element_by_id('email-7c971ed6b4be6cc6') 
Name.send_keys(data["Mail"])

keyboard.press("enter")
```

I need help and tryed everything possible for me. If i change the "enter" to "a" it works but i need the enter. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Key.enter` instead of `"enter"`.
If you need to use another "special" key like `esc` basically do `Key.key_name`